# Lagrangian method for finding Lorentz transformation

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, inertial-frames

Consider a very general case: one reference system (x', y', z') is moving away from another fixed system (x, y, z) with constant speed $v$ (like in the fig. a little bit below).

Normally, using the Minkowski diagram method, we would obtain this relation

$t'$=$t\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$ (1)   (Lorentz eq. specific to the situation)

Now, the question is:

**Can we get the same eq. (eq. 1 from above) using the relativistic Lagrangian method, not the Minkowski diagram method? If you find the example too specific, feel free to use another one, however regardless of the example, it needs to be used in order to get a Lorentz type equation, like eq. 1 from above**

[image]

I started this way:

$$\frac{d\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}\right)}{dt}-\frac{dL}{dx}=0,$$ since there are no forces, and $$L=-mc^2\sqrt{1-\dot{x}^2/c^2}$$ ($t$ is time in $(x, y, z)$ frame and v=$\dot{x}$.)

I notate $\beta$=$\dot{x}/c$. Then, the above eq. becomes $\frac{mc\beta}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}$=C, where C is a constant.

And so, $$\beta=C\sqrt{\frac{1}{m^2c^2+C^2}}$$

Or $$\frac{v}{c}=C\sqrt{\frac{1}{m^2c^2+C^2}}$$

From here I am stuck and I don't know how to continue to get eq. 1

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're trying to do here.  You've found that the solutions to the Euler-Lagrange equations are effectively $v = \text{constant}$.  For a particular solution, $C$ is determined by the particle's speed ($C = m c \beta/\sqrt{1 - \beta^2}$).  But in another reference frame, you'll have a particle moving with a different $\beta$, and so you get a solution with a different $C$;  and I'm not sure there's any way to see how the $C$'s should transform between reference frames without knowing the Lorentz transformations in the first place.

Comment: @Michael Seifert  I was trying to get the last equation ($t'$=$t\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$ if possible...in other words, is it possible using the lagrangian method to obtain such results relating time, space coordinates like we would have  using the minkowski diagram?

Comment: I don't know of any way to do that, and my gut instinct is that there isn't such a way to do it. But maybe someone cleverer than me will come up with a method.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is on hold, and the 2 reasons put in the description can be easily dismantled: 1. **ask about a specific physics concept** - well it does, I am asking if we can use the Lagrangian method in order to get the Lorentz transformation. The situation I gave in the hypothesis can be easily generalized, and I gave it just for the answerer to better understand what I wanted to say (I also mention in my question " I would like, if it is possible, to find the Lorentz transformations related to this figure, but using the relativistic Lagrangian.")

Comment: And 2. **show some effort (to work through the problem)** - again, than I am asking you, the users who put the question on hold (namely @MichaelSeifert and @rob♦ ), than according to your conception, what is everything after "I started this way"? Is it just rambling to you? Are you having problem understanding the equations? This is not my problem, but it is the beginning to this approach.

Comment: FYI, my vote to close was on the "unclear what you're asking" grounds.  If multiple close votes are received with different reasons, the system only displays one.  Beyond this, if you want to ask for more details on why your question was closed, the place to do so would be [Physics Meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @MichaelSeifert  Okay, I now reformulated the question and I hope I made it more clear for everyone